# Cursor - animation javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change this red box with a cursor? I don't want to use an image. thank you

```css
.pointer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  animation-name: mouse;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes mouse {
  0% {
    left: 100px;
    bottom: 0px
  }
  100% {
    left: 500px;
    bottom: 300px
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="pointer"></span>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change something about the red box when the user hovers over it with the mouse cursor?

Comment: @EmilKarlsson I want to replace the box with a cursor

Answer (score 2):

You can use some svg.

```css
.pointer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  animation-name: mouse;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.pointer svg {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes mouse {
  0% {
    left: 100px;
    bottom: 0px
  }
  100% {
    left: 500px;
    bottom: 300px
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="pointer">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="1064.7701 445.5539 419.8101 717.0565" enable-background="new 1064.7701 445.5539 419.8101 717.0565" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#FF0000" points="1283.1857,1127.3097 1406.1421,1077.6322 1314.2406,850.1678 1463.913,852.7823 1093.4828,480.8547   1085.4374,1005.6964 1191.2842,899.8454 "/>
</svg>
</span>
```

Comment: to change svg color is just change the hex of fill on polygon, i've has eddited.
if this has helped you can you mark as solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
.pointer:hover{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css hover selector `.pointer:hover{}` or you make it with Javascript:

```
const elem.document.querySelector(".pointer");
elem.addEventListener("mouseover", yourFunction());
```